# python tuple name same as value name

Tags: python, tuples

I was just playing around with tuples in an effort to learn python

```
a=("1","2")
(a,b) = a
print a
prints '1'
```

a.) If a tuple is a comma separated list of value (http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) why does python allow the value variable name to be the same as the tuple variable name.

b.)In this case, If I want to print the original tuple can I do anything else other than `print (a,b)`

Comment: There could be a legitimate use for this (albeit infrequent - reusing variables tends to reduce clarity), so Python doesn't prevent you from doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You are just reassigning a. This would be similar to

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = b
```

b) You can't print the original tuple because you have resigned the variable and thus the information is lost. A way to avoid this would be to use a different variable name:

```
t = ("1","2")
(a,b) = t
print t
```

This would print `('1','2')`

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is a multiple assignment. Python interprets the following line:

```
(a,b) = a
```

as saying to take the object referred to by the variable `a`, treat it as a 2-element sequence (raising an error if `a` is not such a sequence), and assign the elements to the variables `a` and `b`.

If that's not what you wanted to do, do something else.